# How do I pull a private docker image into crio?

Tags: docker, containerd, cri-o, crictl

I'm debugging why a container runs fine locally with docker but not on a k8s backend.  One of the steps I'd like to debug is running the image locally with `crictl` like k8s does instead of docker.

I have `crio` up locally on my machine but I can't pull the problem image into the crio repo because it's in a private gcr.io repo that requires `gcloud` to authenticate.

As I understand, I cannot configure `crictl` to authenticate with `gcloud` (or else I haven't been able to find such documentation).  But I can configure the `containerd` service to authenticate as a service account.  I'm just a dev so I don't think I should set up my local machine to have a service account authentication with my companies private repo like the k8s node does.

Now I do have the image pulled in my docker repo, which is *(allegedly)* just a file on my computer.  And the crio repo is *(allegedly)* just a file on my computer.  Is there some way to copy the image over locally?  Or do I have to figure out `crictl` authentication?

Comment: This seems like a really complicated to go about debugging the container. Are typical tools (like looking at container logs, setting a custom ENTRYPOINT in the container so that you can `kubectl exec` into it and test things manually, etc) not useful for some reason?

Comment: @larsks, I've looked at logs and such.  The issue is very subtle in a large process so there's not much to exec.  I'm trying to pinpoint if it's the VM, crio, or k8s.  I think it's the vm but I want to eliminate crio as the culprit.